# handleMessage(): Unknown protocol: id = 47, name = udp -- in module (inet::MessageDispatcher) during network initialization

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to broadcast a packet in order to discover neighborhood, when I run the simulation I got this erro : 
handleMessage(): Unknown protocol: id = 47, name = udp -- in module (inet::MessageDispatcher) SaaS.host[0].at (id=77), during network initialization

My code:

```
#ifndef MYAPP_H_
#define MYAPP_H_

#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"
#include "inet/transportlayer/contract/udp/UdpSocket.h"

#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;
using namespace inet;

class myApp : public cSimpleModule, public UdpSocket::ICallback
{
    protected:
        int localPort = -1, destPort = -1;
        bool dontFragment = false;
        const char *packetName = nullptr;
        UdpSocket socket;
        cMessage *selfMsg = nullptr;

    protected:

        void initialize() override;

        void socketDataArrived(UdpSocket *socket, Packet *packet) override;
        void socketErrorArrived(UdpSocket *socket, Indication *indication) override;
        void socketClosed(UdpSocket *socket) override;

    public:
       myApp() {}
       ~myApp();
};



#endif /* MYAPP_H_ */

#include "myApp.h"
#include "inet/applications/base/ApplicationPacket_m.h"
#include "inet/applications/udpapp/UdpBasicApp.h"
#include "inet/common/ModuleAccess.h"
#include "inet/common/TagBase_m.h"
#include "inet/common/TimeTag_m.h"
#include "inet/common/lifecycle/ModuleOperations.h"
#include "inet/common/packet/Packet.h"
#include "inet/networklayer/common/FragmentationTag_m.h"
#include "inet/networklayer/common/L3AddressResolver.h"
#include "inet/transportlayer/contract/udp/UdpControlInfo_m.h"

Define_Module(myApp);

myApp::~myApp()
{
    EV << "App destructor" << endl;
    cancelAndDelete(selfMsg);
}

void myApp::initialize()
{
        localPort = par("localPort");
        destPort = par("destPort");
        packetName = par("packetName");
        socket.setOutputGate(gate("socketOut"));
        socket.bind(localPort);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
        socket.setCallback(this);
        std::ostringstream str;
        str << getId();
        Packet *packet = new Packet(str.str().c_str());
        if(dontFragment)
            packet->addTagIfAbsent<FragmentationReq>()->setDontFragment(true);
        const auto& payload = makeShared<ApplicationPacket>();
        payload->setChunkLength(B(par("messageLength")));
        payload->addTag<CreationTimeTag>()->setCreationTime(simTime());
        packet->insertAtBack(payload);
        L3Address address;
        L3AddressResolver().tryResolve("255.255.255.255", address);
        emit(packetSentSignal, packet);
        socket.sendTo(packet, address, destPort);
}

void myApp::socketDataArrived(UdpSocket *socket, Packet *packet)
{
    EV << "Data Arrived " << endl;
}

 void myApp::socketErrorArrived(UdpSocket *socket, Indication *indication)
{
    EV << "Error Arrived" << endl;
}

void myApp::socketClosed(UdpSocket *socket)
{
    EV << "Close socket" << endl;
}
```

I don't know how to do this, I need to discover neighbors and then to send a different packet to each of them.